# find matching URLs in a line, then shorten them to the domain name

Tags: text-processing, scripting, grep

I have a log file I am writing a script for so it only shows certain fields of output. The last bit I need is to shorten the URL's so that it stops the line when they hit ".com," ".edu," ".org" and so on. Is there a way to do this with grep? Should I be looking towards other commands?

The example output is:

```
student1234 "GET https://www.noname.com:443/login"
student4567 "GET http:// www.noip.edu:80/start/noname"
student8901 "GET http:// www.testing.org:80/search/change"
```

What I need is:

```
student1234 "GET https://www.noname.com
student4567 "GET http:// www.noip.edu
student8901 "GET http:// www.testing.org
```

Comment: Show an example of the log messages and your expected result.

Comment: @jordanm
an example is as follows: 
student1234 "GET http://www.noname.com:80/nothing/login.php"
student5678 "GET https://www.noname.edu:443/nothing/find/something"
What I need is:
student1234 "GET http://www.noname.com
Pretty much to cut it short before the port used.

Comment: Are those different lines or single line?

Comment: @heemayl They are each a different line. Sorry for the messy example. Not sure how to best format in here.

Comment: Please add that to your question..Also you don't want `student5678 "GET noname.edu`?

Comment: @heemayl I added the changes above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So many options, pick the one you like.

Using `grep`:

```
grep -o '^[^:]\+:[^:]\+' file.txt
```

using `cut`:

```
cut -d: -f1-2 file.txt
```

using `awk`:

```
awk -F: '{ print $1$2 }' file.txt
```

using `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\([^:]\+:[^:]\+\).*/\1/' file.txt
```

using shell:

```
while IFS=: read -r i j k; do echo "$i$j"; done <file.txt
```

using `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/^([^:]+:[^:]+).*/$1/' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ grep -o '^[^:]\+:[^:]\+' file.txt
student1234 "GET https://www.noname.com
student4567 "GET http:// www.noip.edu
student8901 "GET http:// www.testing.org

$ cut -d: -f1-2 file.txt                                                
student1234 "GET https://www.noname.com
student4567 "GET http:// www.noip.edu
student8901 "GET http:// www.testing.org

$ awk -F: '{ print $1$2 }' file.txt                 
student1234 "GET https//www.noname.com
student4567 "GET http// www.noip.edu
student8901 "GET http// www.testing.org

$ sed 's/^\([^:]\+:[^:]\+\).*/\1/' file.txt            
student1234 "GET https://www.noname.com
student4567 "GET http:// www.noip.edu
student8901 "GET http:// www.testing.org

$ while IFS=: read -r i j k; do echo "$i$j"; done <file.txt
student1234 "GET https//www.noname.com
student4567 "GET http// www.noip.edu
student8901 "GET http// www.testing.org

$ perl -pe 's/^([^:]+:[^:]+).*/$1/' file.txt
student1234 "GET https://www.noname.com
student4567 "GET http:// www.noip.edu
student8901 "GET http:// www.testing.org
```

Comment: These are almost perfect for what I need. When I tested them, it was cutting off at http or https (after the first : used). It there any way to get it to cut off after the second one?

Comment: @sudo_maas hold on..thats because you have changed the input..

Comment: changed the input?

Comment: I ran it again and got it to work. I appologize, I must have not typed something right. Thank you for all of your help! You are a life saver!